# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth'. Did you mean 'dashboard' instead?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to make a dashboard for my Discord bot, And I use the Flask to do that.

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth'. Did you mean 'dashboard' instead?

This error appeared out of nowhere and now I can't get rid of it.

```py
# main.py

...
@app.route('/auth')
def login():
    return discord.create_session(scope=["identify", "guilds"])

...

@app.route('/', endpoint="main")
def index_page():
    auth = False
    userfetch = None
    if discord.authorized:
        auth = True
        userfetch = discord.fetch_user()
        
    return render_template("index.html", authed=auth, user=userfetch)
...
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

...
{% if not authed %}
<div class="px-2 d-flex">
    <a href="{{ url_for('auth') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
 </div>
              {% else %}
              <div class="px-2 d-flex">
    <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}" class="btn btn-primary"><img>{{user.avatar_url}}</img>Dashboard</a>
 </div>
              {% endif %}
...
```

I just can't get my head around this, I tried changing endpoints for both routes, it still errors. I tried searching on google, still no luck.
I'm using [Flask-Discord](https://github.com/weibeu/Flask-Discord) for discord stuff.

If this is an unrecommended library, please give me suggestions what to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ url_for('auth') }}
```

instead try

```
{{ url_for('login') }}
```

or if blueprint

```
{{ url_for('.login') }}
```